# code review: is this an acceptable use of arbitrary argument list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Came across a coding challenge that introduced a few new concepts to me namely tupes and arbitrary argument lists.

The objective was to sort and return the lowest number in a list. All though this solution passes and could have been achieved in one line...

**I'm wondering if I unpacked the argument list efficiently here and whether or not this code will break eventually.**

```
   def find_smallest_int(*arr):
        z = [];
        for i in arr:
            z += i
            z.sort()
        return z[0]
```

Test cases below all pass:

```
find_smallest_int([78, 56, 232, 12, 11, 43])
find_smallest_int([78, 56, -2, 12, 8, -33])
find_smallest_int([0, 1-2**64, 2**64])
```

Comment: Stack Exchange has a [codereview.se] site. Please read their Help Center ***first*** to make sure your question is on-topic, then delete it here and ask it there. Please don't cross-post.

Comment: You can't add an integer to a list, you can append it to the list, but `[] + 78` won't work.

Comment: For starters, your code does not follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines. You also misspelled "tuples".

Comment: Why are you you defining your function to accept arbitrary arguments when all it does is accept one list? There's no point in unpacking the list when you're just going to iterate over it in the body of your function. And why are you trying to add things and call `z.sort()` on every iteration when your entire function body could just be `return arr.sort()[0]`?

Comment: @Grismar They're not adding an integer to a list. They're adding a *list* to a list.

Comment: @KellyBundy they are, but from the rest of the code and the wording of the question, it doesn't look like they think they are. Of course, by passing the arguments as an actual list, this makes the code work, but likely not for reasons OP thinks. Once the brackets go, the code won't work for the reason I stated - but you're right to point out that a bit more context would have been helpful.

Comment: `*arr` is for accepting multiple arguments, but you only ever pass the function one (a single list). Also, why sort `z` after each addition? Just do it once after everything has been added to it.